# threejs - Reset camera position/rotation when using PointerLockControls

Tags: camera, three.js

well i wants to reset the position and the rotation, when i am using the PointerLockControls. Currently i use

```
controls.getObject().position.set( -30, 10, 80 );
controls.getObject().position.y = 10;
```

for the position. But how can i reset the rotation?

I tried different things like:

```
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0));
camera.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
controls.getObject().rotation.x = 0;
controls.getObject().rotation.y = 0;
controls.updateProjectionMatrix();
...
```

Have you an idea?

Greeting,
Johannes

Comment: You can now accept your own answer by clicking on the check mark.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out

```
controls.getObject().rotation.y = 0; // Rotates Yaw Object
controls.getObject().children[0].rotation.x = 0; // Rotates the Pitch Object
```

Now, the Camera is looking in the original direction!

three.js r.62