# Threejs store and load camera position and orientation

Tags: three.js

I'm using PointerLockControls to make the camera controllable by the user.

When the user reloads the page I want to restore the cameras position and orientation (where it is looking).

I've tried to get the camera orientation via

```
const lookingAt = this.camera.getWorldDirection()
// persisting lookingAt vector before reload
```

When the page is reloaded, I set the orientation

```
const lookingAt = loadStoredVector();
this.camera.lookAt(lookingAt)
```

Unfortunately it's to the right direction

I now also tried now :

```
 const lookingAt = new THREE.Vector3();
 const cameraLookingAt = this.pointerLookControl.getDirection(lookingAt);

 ....

 this.camera.lookAt(lookingAt);
```

But also doesn't work

Comment: `getWorldDirection()` returns a vector indicating the direction the object is pointing, whereas `lookAt ()` expects a point at which to look. So, those two aren't compatible, and using the output of one for the input of the other will likely not produce the desired results. Also, neither the world direction nor the 'look at' function uniquely specify an orientation. I'm not familiar with Three.js, but I'm guessing there's a way to query and set object orientations (e.g. via quarternion). If so, that's probably what you're looking for.

Comment: I should add that if the 'look at' function uses a fixed 'up' or other reference vector (which is likely), probably all you need in order to store the camera orientation is its position, and a point that it's looking at. Adding the return value of `getWorldDirection()` to the camera position should give you the latter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098775/threejs-reset-camera-position-rotation-when-using-pointerlockcontrols I realize the answer is from `r62`, so it might not work anymore.

Comment: Thanks @Marquizzo but didn't work. This affests the camera yaw and roll but not the direction where the camera is looking at.

Comment: I'm not sure what 'pointerLookControl' is, but you seem to be making the same mistake in your edit as in your original code (unless getDirection() does something different than I think it does). This is a bit of a guess based on the context, but again, I think in the statement `this.camera.lookAt(lookingAt);`, you want to use not 'lookingAt' as the argument, but rather the sum of 'lookingAt' and the camera position. I would at least give that a try if you haven't already (and maybe also try camera.getWorldDirection(), as you were doing initially).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, by going to the source-code of the [PointerLockControls](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/PointerLockControls) of three.js.

It works by storing:

```
this.camera.quaternion // has x,y,z,w components that I pass via the URL query string
this.camera.position // has x,y,z components that I pass via the URL query
```

I can restore the camera position and orientation via:

```
// position
this.camera.position.x = posX;
this.camera.position.y = posY;
this.camera.position.z = posZ;

// orientation
const cameraQuanternion = new THREE.Quaternion(qx,qy,qz,qw);
this.camera.quaternion = cameraQuanternion;
```

Maybe this can help somebody

Comment: For what it's worth, I mentioned that earlier: "I'm not familiar with Three.js, but I'm guessing there's a way to query and set object orientations (e.g. via quarternion). If so, that's probably what you're looking for." In any case, glad you solved it :)